# Sort by length of nested JSON array

Tags: json, postgresql, sorting

Let's assume I have a PostgreSQL table with following schema:

```
id: 1,
attribute_a: 'value'
attribute_b: 'value'
data: { attribute_c: 'value', array_of_values: [1,2,3] }
```

Where `data` is stored in a JSON structure. Is that possible to order the elements in the table by array_of_values length?

Comment: Sure it is! Have a look at `json_array_length(json)` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_array_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) or [`jsonb_array_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) like [Eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056757/eggplant) commented. Assuming `jsonb`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY jsonb_array_length(data -> 'array_of_values')
```

BTW, the syntax for your JSON value should be:

```
{"attribute_c": "value", "array_of_values": [1, 2, 3]}
```